# Excel counting cells pasted as values from cells that contain a formula wiht a "" as result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy, paste

Since I think I'm not expressing myself clear, I added some images:

As title reads,

I have a formula in a range C2 in Sheet1 something like this =IF(a2=2,2,""), and this is a recurrent formula from C2 to C21.

Sometimes the result is 2, but sometimes the result is "" which leaves an empty cell.

[image: Range with Formulas]

The problem is when i copy that range of cells and paste it as values in E2, it counts the empty cells, (the ones which result was "" in previous column) as if they were filled with some characters or something.

[image: Counting Empty Cells pasted as values]

As you see in image above it counts 20, instead of only 5.

I tried to copy the range of empty cells and paste it into different text editors to see if i can find an odd character or something but no, they look only like enters.

Is there a way I can copy cells that contains a formula with "empty/nothing" results, and paste them as values and as empty cells for excel not to take them into account to perform the counting, they are also being taken into account in pivot tables.

Is there a special character that I could replace, like for example when i want to remove all carriage returns in a range of cells, i use the replace function in Ctrl+H and then in find what: ctrl+j and in replace with: (i leave it empty), and this removes all carriage returns included in cells, leaving all comments in a single line.

I usually have to go thru all the columns with same situation of fake empty cells, and delete them manually after i filter them (they are even displayed as blanks when filtering them).

Even if I use the Find & Select - Special - Blanks, it wont select the fake empty cells.

I look all around the google globe and wasn't able to find an answer.

I hope you guys can understand what i explained above and can help me.

Thanks in advance for your appreciated support.

Regards

Comment: You need to filter data to show cells that are not empty then copy and paste visible cells only. After filtering select all cells and hit `ALT+;` Alter and semicolone same time to select visible cells only.

Comment: hum maybe I'm to dumb or something, i just cant get the instruction you provided. can you elaborate a little bit more on your answer? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Note that this doesn't happen when you have numbers and `COUNT`, but when you have text or numbers and you do `COUNTA`. You could apply a filter which would show only those empty cells and select them all and press `DEL`. If you're interested in a VBA solution, it could be solved in the way that you select the range and run the code, something like `ALT+8` and `ENTER` if you don't have other macros in the workbook.

Comment: Another 'ugly' solution could be to change the way you count in the resulting (copied) column, e.g. instead of `=COUNTA(A1:A1000)`, you could use `=COUNTA(A1:A1000)-COUNTBLANK(A1:A1000)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pasted cells are not really blank - if you turn on "Transition Navigation Keys" in File > Options > Advanced under the subheading Lotus Compatibility and you'll see there is an apostrophe in each of the "empty" cells.

[image]

What you've done is inserting a zero-length string into each of the cells which doesn't fulfil your if-criteria. These strings are then copied to the range you are pasting to.

---

To remove them quickly, there are a couple of options.

**Using find and replace:**

1. Select all the cells Press Ctrl + H to open the Find and Replace
   window
2. Leave the Find What box empty
3. In the Replace With box,type a string that is not in the data, such as "$$$$"
4. Click the Replace All button, to Replace all the blanks with $$$$
5. Next, put "$$$$" in the Find What box and leave the Replace With box empty
6. Click the Replace All button, to replace all the $$$$ entries with nothing

**Using text to columns**

1. Select all the cells
2. On the Excel Ribbon, click the Data tab and selcect Text to Columns
3. In the dialog which pops up, select Delimited, then click the Finish button

---

I found all this info [on the Contextures blog](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2011/04/13/fix-blank-excel-cells-copied-from-database/), which goes into some more detail about the problem, as well as presenting a couple more ways to solve it.

Comment: ok, i think there is no option than replace the empty cells with another text, then replace that new text with an empty box in the "Replace with" in the Find and replace window. Thanks, I'll use the macro to make this process faster! :)